# Unable to execute pefcmdlets in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run New-PefTraceSession, but it shows error as

```
New-PefTraceSession : The term 'New-PefTraceSession' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
 or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
```

I tried to install the module as install-module pef but it showed error as

```
PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'PEF'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1375 char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
```

Comment: You need to install [Message Analyzer from the Microsoft Download Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226)

Answer (score 1):

[Using powershell to automate tracing](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/messageanalyzer/2013/10/29/using-powershell-to-automate-tracing/):

> While tracing with a UI is simple, it has limitations today. When it comes to tracing a sticky problem, you need extensibility and flexibility in order to instrument when to start and stop a trace. We facilitate this in Message Analyzer by leveraging PowerShell and a new set of Cmdlets **which ship with Message Analyzer** which you can download from the Microsoft Download Center.

You can download the message analyzer [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226).

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having trouble after installing the Microsoft Message Analyzer msi package, here's the cmdlet's online documentation: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456526(v=wps.630).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Copy the folder **PEF** from

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Message Analyzer\PowerShell`

to

`C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`.

Then the module PEF is available and the `cmdlet` works.